# Incorrect URL on git SSL

Tags: git

If I run `git fetch`  i receive the following error, note the incorrect URL for github, how do I fix that?

```
git fetch
fatal: unable to access 'https://githun.com/200mg/test.git/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a typo: https://githun.com/200mg/test.git/

This should be: https://github.com/200mg/test.git/

To change the remote's address, assuming it's named 'origin':

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/200mg/test.git/
```

Comment: OP: *note the incorrect URL for github*. I guess OP knows about the typo. The question is regarding how to change the url